# Google Analytics tracking for groups or individuals

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

not sure how many people on Stack Overflow use google analytics however thought it might be worth asking the following.

We send out email campaigns as a business and using GA we can track when a user has clicked on a link in the email to come through to our site. We can therefore see how many people come to the site based on that individual email.

What we then want to be able to do is track the journey they take on the site before purchasing a product (or until they leave the site). How do we track this period between reaching the site and actually placing an order? If it is not possible to track actual individuals (I know it is a grey area within Google terms), is there a way of tracking all users that come in from that email as a group so for example we can say

'10 people from the email viewed x product page, then y product page then ordered but 5 people visited z product page and then left the site'.

Just to make things even more difficult if people are accessing the site from multiple IP addresses e.g. Phones, Internet Cafe etc is it possible?

If they do buy a product we can then track the status of their order from within our own CRM system.

I know Google as the 'Visitor Flow' feature but you do't seem to be able to isolate individuals or campaigns through it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a different landing page for each of your campaigns.  This is a good idea anyway (you want the landing page to be very relevant to your campaign message), and it makes it trivial to use Google Analytics' Visitor Flow feature to see the journey they took after leaving that page.  This is an easy win for tracking at the campaign level.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is useful so I've added a uptick. Does anyone have any alternative solutions however, possibly ones that can be used on historical data?